# float output from php function

Tags: php, replace

I have a simple php replace function, that I need to return a "0" (for resale) and a "1" (for newbuilt)

```
. function multi_rep2( $oldVar = '' ) {
    $searchVal2 = array("newbuilt", "resale");
    $replaceVal2 = array("1", "0");
    return str_replace($searchVal2, $replaceVal2, $oldVar);
}
```

In my output I get "1", but not "0". I figured out that I have to convert the zero to a float value to be returned. I tried a few things with the floatval() function, but can not get it to work.

Anyone who can set me in the right direction?

Kind, regards.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the application. I tried both examples in the comments and it doesn't work. If I use an other number than "0" it does work. I will contact the developer of the application and I will post the solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As expected the problem is a bug in the php editor I was using (as part of the WordPress plugin All Import/Export). In the editor the result was a blank space instead of "0". In the output xml file the "0" did appear. So all is fine. The developer will look at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly :

```
function multi_rep2( $oldVar = '' ) {
    $searchVal2 = array("newbuilt", "resale");
    $replaceVal2 = array("1", "0");
    return str_replace($searchVal2, $replaceVal2, $oldVar);
}

$t = 'Hello i am newbuilt and not resale, bye';
var_dump(multi_rep2($t));
// string(27) "Hello i am 1 and not 0, bye"
```

Are you sure "resale" is in your string ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. If I replace the "0" for any other number it shows. Thanks for your feedback. I suspect the problem is in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused to why you need to convert the zero to a float?
I tried this out in a PHP sandbox and it seems to work fine.

```
$oldVar = 'newbuilt and resale'; 
    $searchVal2 = array("newbuilt", "resale");
    $replaceVal2 = array(1, 0);
    $rep = str_replace($searchVal2, $replaceVal2, $oldVar);
    echo $rep;
```

This echoes "1 and 0" instead of "newbuilt and resale".

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I suspect the problem is in the application.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, this function works. To parse the value to float do something like:

```
function multi_rep2( $oldVar = '' ) {
    $searchVal2 = array("newbuilt", "resale");
    $replaceVal2 = array("1", "0");
    return floatval(str_replace($searchVal2, $replaceVal2, $oldVar));
}
// yields: float(0)
var_dump(multi_rep2('resale'));
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e838ad5db6ace47fde1ff8925da5d9baa956ee2)

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work. Thanks for your feedback. I suspect the problem is in the application.